# JSON feed - How can I have only 1 item parsed daily for an Amazon Alexa Flash briefing

Tags: json, list, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a Flash Briefing for Amazon Alexa enabled devices that will provide information each day. I've started creating the json file with the information needed and did a test on my Echo Dot to ensure the json is setup correctly.

My question now is how do I make it so that Alexa only reads 1 item each day? Currently when I ask Alexa to ready my flash briefing she reads all 3. I'd like to have a months worth or more entered into the json file and not have to update it daily.

```
[
  {
    "uid": "DAILY_TIP_ITEM_JSON_TTS_0001",
    "updateDate": "2018-02-20T00:00:00.0Z",
    "titleText": "Today's Motivation",
    "mainText": "This is number one.",
    "redirectionUrl": "#"
   },
  {
    "uid": "DAILY_TIP_ITEM_JSON_TTS_0002",
    "updateDate": "2018-02-21T00:00:00.0Z",
    "titleText": "Today's Motivation",
    "mainText": "This is number two.",
    "redirectionUrl": "#"
  },
  {
    "uid": "DAILY_TIP_ITEM_JSON_TTS_0003",
    "updateDate": "2018-02-23T00:00:00.0Z",
    "titleText": "Today's Motivation",
    "mainText": "This is number three.",
    "redirectionUrl": "#"
  }
]
```

My first thought was to create a date key in each item and use an if statement to compare the dates. Is that the best approach or does anyone have a better idea? As you can see in the 3rd item, I used a future date to see if Alexa would ignore it until that date, but she still reads it even though today is the 21st.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I can answer for this as a reference to others.

You're better off updating the feed (dynamically somehow) to show only 1 item if you only want one item read. per the [Flashing Briefing API Feed Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/flashbriefing/flash-briefing-skill-api-feed-reference.html#feed-format-requirements):

> - Provide between 1 and 5 unique feed items at a time.
>
>   - If more items are provided, Alexa ignores items beyond the first five.
>   - Items should be provided in order from newest to oldest, based on the date value for the item. Alexa may ignore older items.

So, Alexa will read up to five items, from newest to oldest.